# What does $\operatorname{supp}(A)$ mean?

Tags: functional-analysis, notation, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

I'm looking at a paper (specifically [this one](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0608016v3.pdf)).  In the paper, we have a positive operator $A$, and the operator $\operatorname{supp}(A)$ is supposed to be a projection operator.

Does anybody know what exactly $\operatorname{supp}$ is supposed to mean in this context? I suppose there must be a connection to the idea of the "support of a function", which would be a space.  Perhaps $\operatorname{supp}(A)$ is meant to be the projection onto the orthogonal complement of the kernel.

In any case, I'm not sure what's meant here.  Thanks for looking.

Comment: Also, if someone knows what $\overline{A}$ could mean, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Could this be related:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)?

Comment: $\overline{A}$ most likely means the closure of the closable operator $A$.

Comment: @EmmadKareem those are sets though, not operators, hence my issue.

Comment: @DanielFischer I think we're assumed to be on a finite dimensional vector space, so that doesn't seem right.  Thanks for the guess though.

Comment: Then it might be a conjugate. Have we a distinguished basis?

Comment: @DanielFischer We do have a distinguished basis

Comment: @DanielFischer and I think they like to use $*$ for conjugate in quantum

Comment: What do they use for the adjoint then? $\dagger$?

Comment: @DanielFischer yep!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Then from the identity on the page 2 $\overline{U_w}^\dagger=U_w^\top$ it should really mean complex conjugate.

Comment: Sometimes the orthogonal complement of the kernel is called support. So I believe that your guess (orthogonal projection to the complement) is correct.

Comment: "With some abuse of notation, we identify a projector with the support of
the space on which it projects. We denote the support of an operator $A$ by supp($A$)." ([Here, page 55](http://dare.uva.nl/document/2/129870))

Answer (score 3):

The paper is a bit short on explaining the notations that they perhaps consider to be common in the quantum world. The notations are available, for example, in [this PhD thesis](http://dare.uva.nl/document/2/129863)

- On page 51:

  > Let $\overline{P}$ be the entry-wise complex conjugate of P.
- On page 55:

  > With some abuse of notation, we identify a projector with the support of the space on which it projects. We denote the support of an operator $A$ by supp($A$).